# Every Same model has same service uuid?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Each ble device has, one mac address, one or more services, one or more characteristics.
Can I guarantee the every devices with same model with same manufacturer has same service and characteristic uuid?

I can guess that mac address will be different, but will the service uuid and characteristic uuid be same?

If I have one more device then It's easy to figure out but I don't have it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GATT services describe device's features. Characteristics describe what and how service can do.

If your device follows Bluetooth standard and provides well-known predefined feature *for example, Blood Pressure sensor) then yes, you can be sure that it always will have identical set of services and characteristics.

If your device is something custom and provides custom services then no, you can not be sure that services and characteristics will be identical for each device.

About MAC: BLE has two MAC types: public and private. If device advertises its MAC as public then it is always be the same. In case of private MAC device will advertise random MAC that can be changed each time your device turned ON or each time you discover it (depends on implementation). So for MAC you can not be sure that it always the same.